# Add object to map with bumpersensor

Tags: navigation, kinect, roomba, stack, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am using navigation stack for my navigation.
I use Kinect combined with depthimage to laserscan to get an accurate laserscan.
The only problem with the Kinect of course is that it uses infrared signal therefore it sees through glass and will not detect cetain object.

For the base I am using a roomba. This roomba contains a bump sensor. I want to build when the bump sensor bumps into an object it places a static object on the map which cannot be removed. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249722/add-object-to-map-with-bumpersensor/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps the easiest solution is to write a node that converts bumper messages to a datatype that can be processed by a [costmap2d obstacle_layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles) ([this looks like a potential solution](http://answers.ros.org/question/58111/bumper-in-the-gmapping-costmap-turtlebot/)). I would also make a separate costmap layer for just the bumper sensor to avoid the Kinect marking the region as clear.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1